# Strange "padding" at chart area after updating chart.js (2.8.0 -> 3.4.1)

Tags: javascript, chart.js, chart.js3

Sorry for my bad english.

After updating chart.js from 2.8.0 to 3.4.1 I saw strange "paddings" (left and right) at chart area (please look a screenshot).

[image: padding].

On official website in Samples, you can see line charts without any paddings. But I saw it in sample of bar charts (may be some settings of bar chart can take effect?).

Here is the code of chart configuration, chart instantiation, plugins and template with styles:

```js
// chart options
chartOptions = {
        type: "line",
        data: {
            datasets: [],
        },
        options: {
            elements: {
                point: { radius: 0 },
                line: { tension: 0, borderWidth: 1 }
            },
            animation: false,
            resizeDelay: 100,
            responsive: true,
            maintainAspectRatio: true,
            legend: { display: false },
            tooltips: {
                mode: 'nearest',
                intersect: false,
                callbacks: {label: (item, data) => this.onLabel(item, data)}
            },
            hover: {
                mode: 'nearest',
                intersect: false,
            },
            scales: {
                x: {
                    offset: true,
                    stacked: true,
                    type: 'time',
                    time: {
                        tooltipFormat: 'DD MMMM YYYY HH:mm:ss',
                        displayFormats: {
                            millisecond: 'HH:mm:ss.SSS',
                            second: 'HH:mm:ss',
                            minute: 'HH:mm',
                            hour: 'HH:mm',
                            day: 'DD MMM',
                        },
                    },
                    ticks: {
                        major: {
                            enabled: true,
                            fontStyle: 'bold',
                            fontColor: 'rgb(54, 143, 3)'
                        },
                        sampleSize: 10,
                        maxRotation: 30,
                        minRotation: 30,
                        min: undefined,
                        max: undefined,
                    },
                    afterFit: (scale) => {
                        scale.height = 40;
                    }
                },
                A: {
                    id: 'A',
                    type: 'linear',
                    position: 'left',
                    display: 'auto',
                    ticks: {
                        backdropPadding: 0,
                    },
                },
                B: {
                    id: 'B',
                    type: 'linear',
                    position: 'right',
                    display: 'auto',
                    ticks: {
                        max: 2,
                        min: -1,
                        stepSize: 1,
                        suggestedMin: 0,
                        suggestedMax: 1,
                    },
                },
            },
            plugins: {
                zoom: {
                    pan: {
                        enabled: true,
                        mode: 'xy',
                        overScaleMode: 'y',
                        rangeMax: {x: new Date()},
                        onPanComplete: chart => this.onZoom(chart, false)
                    },
                    zoom: {
                        wheel: {
                            enabled: true,
                        },
                        mode: 'xy',
                        overScaleMode: 'y',
                        onZoomComplete: chart => this.onZoom(chart, true)
                    }
                }
            },
        },
    } as Chart.ChartConfiguration<'line'>;

// call of Chart#register()
import zoomPlugin from 'chartjs-plugin-zoom';
Chart.Chart.register(
    Chart.TimeScale, Chart.LinearScale, Chart.LineController,
    Chart.PointElement, Chart.LineElement, zoomPlugin,
);

// chart instantiating
this.chart = new Chart.Chart<'line'>(this.chartContainer.nativeElement, this.chartOptions);
```

Template

```html
<div class="chart-wrapper">
    <canvas #chart_container id="chart"></canvas>
</div>
```

Styles

```css
.chart-wrapper {
    width: 99%;
    height: calc(100% - 7px);
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

What I tried:

1. Check data and datasets;
2. Disable chartjs-zoom-plugin;
3. Set `options.layout.padding` to 0;
4. Set `options.responsive` to `false`;
5. Set `data.datasets.borderWidth` to 1;

**How I can remove this "padding"?**

Comment: Can you provide a working example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behaviour comes from the `offset` options, this option is in the scale so bars dont render on the gridLines but they show nicely between them. As the documentation states bar charts automatically set this option to true while by default it is false:https://www.chartjs.org/docs/master/axes/cartesian/#common-options-to-all-cartesian-axes

You can manually override this to be false but then the first and last bar in that chart will look weird since they get rendered at half width:

```js
var options = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
        label: '# of Votes',
        data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
        borderColor: 'red',
        backgroundColor: 'red'
      },
      {
        label: '# of Points',
        data: [7, 11, 5, 8, 3, 7],
        type: 'bar',
        backgroundColor: 'blue'
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      x: {
        offset: false
      }
    }
  }
}

var ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.4.0/chart.js"></script>
</body>
```